# How to connect mysql database in eclipse using maven and jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, spring-data-jpa

I want to connect to mysql database from eclipse. I want to create a Rest Api and insert data in mysql database.

I am using sqlyog to connect to mysql and I have installed a xammp server, turned on the mysql and my project is located at tihs path C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\

I have connected sql yog by giving the port on which mysql is running from xammp server.

Now I have created one maven project, which includes jpa dependency and properties.

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.creditone</groupId>
    <artifactId>creditone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>creditone</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.datasource.name=test 
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.database=mysql 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect \u2013
```

Main controller

```
 package com.creditone.creditone;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.creditone.creditone.User;
import com.creditone.creditone.UserRepository;

@Controller    // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
    @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
               // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
            , @RequestParam String email) {
        // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
        // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

        User n = new User();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setEmail(email);
        userRepository.save(n);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
package com.creditone.creditone;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.creditone.creditone.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

User

```
package com.creditone.creditone;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

Trying to use this code to check if database getting connect and able to perform CRUD operations.

But as I run this I am getting error as :

```
       main] c.c.creditone.CreditoneApplication       : Starting CreditoneApplication on Siddhi with PID 18728 (C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\creditone\target\classes started by siddhi in C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\creditone)
2018-02-20 12:31:45.726  INFO 18728 --- [           main] c.c.creditone.CreditoneApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-20 12:31:45.756  INFO 18728 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6328d34a: startup date [Tue Feb 20 12:31:45 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-20 12:31:46.881  INFO 18728 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99fd5bbe] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-02-20 12:31:47.169  INFO 18728 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-02-20 12:31:47.176  INFO 18728 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.176  INFO 18728 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2018-02-20 12:31:47.181  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Windows\System32;;.]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.236  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-02-20 12:31:47.236  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1483 ms
2018-02-20 12:31:47.339  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.342  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.342  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.342  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.342  INFO 18728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.389  WARN 18728 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2018-02-20 12:31:47.390  INFO 18728 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-02-20 12:31:47.402  INFO 18728 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-20 12:31:47.406 ERROR 18728 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

How to resolve this? I am new to eclipse and web development. Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: try to add to my mysql-connector

Comment: Hi, added mysql connector in pom.xml   <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>          Still its giving same error. @SauloAires

Comment: this one: <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.9-rc</version>
</dependency>

please check the version

Comment: version added is managed:5.1.45 @SauloAires

Comment: not working with adding version <version>8.0.9-rc</version> . Tried to add version <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>  But it gives error, missing artifact id. @SauloAires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application.properties seems to have wrong entries. The only ones you need are the following 4.

1. spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
2. spring.datasource.username=dbuser
3. spring.datasource.password=dbpass
4. spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

It is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

Also where is your application.properties located?

> SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:
>   A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
>   The current directory
>   A classpath /config package
>   The classpath root

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I tried this : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  ... application.properties is located in javaResources/src/main/resources . But dosent work. @Patrick Lauhof

Comment: are you still getting the "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE" error?

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown by Spring when it is unable to find the application.properties file or unable to find the datasource.

1. Check if the application.properties is under src/main/resources. Also, remove \u2013 from the properties file
2. You have not specified the mysql port, are you sure you are able to connect it from command line directly?
3. Since you are running from eclipse, make sure you have added the start-up class appropriately and have @SpringBootApplication

   ```
   <properties>
       <start-class>org.xxx.xxx.YourClassName</start-class>
   </properties>
   ```

Comment: Hi, tried this, still getting the same error. @Chids

Comment: how to connect if no password specified?

Comment: Couldn't think of any other solution!